# How to fill my chart (chart.js) with my own data from API

Tags: javascript, arrays, charts, axios, chart.js

I am trying to figure out how to fill my chart with my own data using Axios. Here is the Chart.js JavaScript code I have:

```
export const getPieChartData = (themes) => ({
 labels: ['Coffee', 'Milk', 'Juice'],
 datasets: [{
    label: '',
    backgroundColor: [themes.primary, themes.warning, themes.danger],
    data: [50, 20, 150],
 }],
})
```

I have to change 'labels' and 'data' array value with data from my API, here is what my API looks like

```
"piechart": [
{
  "category": "Fashion",
  "total": 2000,
  "id": 1
},
{
  "category": "Sport",
  "total": 1000,
  "id": 2
},
{
  "category": "Business",
  "total": 1500,
  "id": 3
}
//and other data
]
```

And the chart looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2oJl.png)

My friend tried this on the js code, but failed to show the data value :

```
    import axios from 'axios';
const labels = [];
const datas = [];
axios.get('http://localhost:3000/piechart').then((response) => {
  // console.log(response.data);
  response.data.forEach(element => {
    labels.push(element.kategori);
    datas.push(element.jumlah);
  });
}, (error) => {
  console.log(error);
});

export const getPieChartData = (themes) => ({
  labels: ["a","b","c"],
  datasets: [{
    label: '',
    backgroundColor: [themes.primary, themes.warning, themes.danger],
    data: [1,2,3],
  }],
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to push them into labels and data in a for loop. i recommend a for of loop
simple like this

```js
axios.get("localhost:3000/piechart").then(
  (response) => {
    console.log(response.data);
    for (const item of piechart) {
      getPieChartData.labels.push(item.category);
      getPieChartData.datasets[0].data.push(item.total);
    }
  },
  (error) => {
    console.log(error);
  }
);
```

Comment: provide this in your initial post message, not here

Comment: But It failed to show data to the chart, (sorry typo)

Comment: it must work. just be sure u pushing the data in the correct arrays of your pieChart.